# Error : Winform Icon Hiding from Taskbar on maximizing Screen

Tags: c#, winforms

I am facing an issue with Winform lately. If I am setting a form to maximize programitically the icon from taskbar Hides.

**My Code.**

```
 public PersonalProfile(string sid)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            StaffUPI = sid;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }
```

**Issue**

The Appllication Icon hides from TaskBar on the pages where I have used Maximized Code.
I dont know Why is this Happening. And is there a fix to this problem.

Comment: What if you try setting the property of form "Window State" maximized ?

Comment: I dont want that on page load. That is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Will do the trick...

A simple way to show ur form on top always.

```
 this.TopMost = true;
 this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```